# Getting AccessToken from Code using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

For Facebook C# SDK version 5.0 we where using

```
FacebookOAuthClient result = new FacebookOAuthClient();
dynamic tokenResult = oAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(code);
```

I have upgraded my Facebook C# SDK to version 6.0 and now there is no `FacebookOAuthClient`.
Its just `FacebookClient` now.

What is the new function that does the OAUth dance of getting `access_token` from `code`?

Comment: @downvoter: care to elaborate? or is it just because you don't get it? :)

Answer (score 1):

FacebookOAuthClient was removed in v6. You can find the alternative method at http://csharpsdk.org/docs/faq.html for v6.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.GetAsync("oauth/access_token", new {
    client_id     = "app_id",
    client_secret = "app_secret",
    redirect_uri  = "http://yoururl.com/callback",
    code          = "code"      
});
```

Comment: you can find the server side example at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-aspnet-sample

Comment: Hi Prabir, This method is has returntype "Void". I am also facing same problem .... You are one of the developers of this SDK, am I right ??

Comment: @pearl's use fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) => { if(e.Error != null) { ... } }; before calling fb.GetAsync or use await fb.GetTaskAsync. 
yes i'm one of the sdk developers.